# Mandatory Profile Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, components

I have an issue with a component (dll) in one of my applications that only occurs on when a user logs in that has a mandatory profile.

My application loads components from a share drive on launch after a successful login and places the dll in a folder.  The dll makes a couple of web service calls and displays the information in a winform.

What I am seeing is that when the user first logs into the pc and launches the application, the app will pull the dll and the component will work the first time it is executed, but fail on any subsequent uses.  If I completely close the application, and re-open, the component will continue to fail.  However, if I log out of the PC and start the process over, it will re-download the dll and again work on the first execution, but fail on subsequent.

**This does not happen with any other profile types.

What would cause something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my issue.  I was using a web service that used the RSACryptoServiceProvider under the covers.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2007/10/23/rsacryptoserviceprovider-fails-when-used-with-mandatory-profiles.aspx